# Two virtual hosts conflict in ubuntu in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, laravel-5

I have made two virtual hosts in ubuntu 14.04 for two different laravel projects. Lets say

```
laravel1.dev and laravel2.dev
```

when i browse laravel1.dev it works fine and the problem is when i browse laravel2.dev it will show all the contents of laravel1.dev until i restart apache2. And so is for laravel2.dev

Comment: It could be anything. Post the relevant DNS and Apache configuration. Also detail precisely every HTTP request and HTTP response. mod_rewrite log could help, too

Comment: it doesnot conflict with any other php frameworks. only laravel

Answer (score 0):

If its local environnement in `/etc/hosts` use something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 laravel1.dev
127.0.0.2 laravel2.dev
```

In `sites-enabled` configure the http request like:

- `127.0.0.1:80` to `laravel1.dev` root directory
- `127.0.0.2:80` to `laravel2.dev` root directory